Next.js: Png file does not render in vercel
I'm developing a project with Next.js and Sass, but when I deployed my project in vercel, the png imagens did not render, the svg files worked without problem.
In the localhost, the png images are rendering, just in vercel not.
The image is into public (line 18)


You should not add the curly braces {} in the src attribute in the <Image> tag.
Try removing it:
<Image width={300} height={300} alt="employer" src="/perfil.png" />

